# How to resolve deadlock because of Select and update statement in multithreading

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which I need to select some row and then update it later. Now between selecting the row and updating it I do not want to allow another session to update the data so I am using repeatable read for this scenario. 
However I have started getting deadlocks. Now to avoid deadlock I am thinking of adding locking hint - UPDLOCK like mentioned below.

```
        -------------session 1-----------

set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
Select new_site_id from abc with (updlock)

update abc set active_site_status = ? where new_site_id = ?
commit transaction
```

Now UPDLOCK hint is not compatible with another UPDLOCK or update statement. But it is compatible with shared locks. So this solution fails when another session executes the below mentioned code -

```
        -------------session 2-----------

set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
Select new_site_id from abc         --This is without updlock

update abc set active_site_status = ? where new_site_id = ?
commit transaction
```

How can I avoid deadlock in this case?. What all options do I have here..
Will snapshot isolation help? If there is a case when I start with - > "set transaction isolation level snapshot" and Session 2 starts with "set transaction isolation level repeatable read" will there still be deadlock or blocking. I am confused badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your situation isn't more complicated than the example, you could try doing this is one statement...

```
UPDATE abc SET active_site_status = ? WHERE new_site_id = (SELECT new_site_id FROM abc)
```

If your case is more complicated, please post the actual code.